# Scraping the timestamp of news published in coindesk.com

Tags: web-scraping

I could not find the timestamp attribute in html code.

Is there any way to extract the exact datetime upto seconds of news published? Coindesk do provide the time upto minutes but, for my project, it is not sufficient. I am not sure?

Comment: We need both HTML code sample and your attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.